# Jquery for chosen not working properly on rails 4 app

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the Mailboxer and Chosen gems. A user can select multiple users from a dropdown menu. The problem is, on the initial load the dropdown appears already opened and allows you to only select one other user. If I reload the page the dropdown appears as it should.

When I check it in the chrome inspector I get [TypeError: undefined is not a function](http://cl.ly/image/290g3B2o380f) error. I've checked S.O, and google and a lot of the advice is to change the order of my application.js file. I have tried this but cannot get this to fire properly on the initial start-up. Looking at my terminal window, every request seems to go through successfully.

[Dropdown on initial load, broken](http://cl.ly/image/2n3r3r2t1S3j)

[Dropdown w/ refresh working properly](http://cl.ly/image/2x1X3D0v1w0R)

So it DOES work, but why do I have to refresh the page to make it work properly?

Application.js:

```
    ...
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require chosen-jquery
//= require bootstrap
//= require jquery.image-select
//= require messages
//= require turbolinks
```

application.css.scss:

```
... 
 *
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */

@import 'bootstrap';
@import 'bootstrap/theme';
@import 'chosen';
...
```

messages.coffee:

```
# Place all the behaviors and hooks related to the matching controller here.
# All this logic will automatically be available in application.js.
# You can use CoffeeScript in this file: http://coffeescript.org/
jQuery ->
  $('.chosen-it').chosen()
```

gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.1.5'


gem 'rails', '4.2.0'

gem 'devise'
gem 'thin'
gem "simple_calendar"

gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate'

gem "mailboxer"

gem 'will_paginate' 

gem 'gravatar_image_tag'

group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
  gem 'annotate'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end

gem 'chosen-rails'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.5'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc


#gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.4'

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin]
```

Offending file, home.html.erb:

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
        <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide">
            <!-- Indicators -->
            <ol class="carousel-indicators hidden-xs">
                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>
            <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                    <%= image_tag "slide-1.jpg", :class => "img-responsive img-full" %>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <%= image_tag "slide-2.jpg", :class => "img-responsive img-full" %>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <%= image_tag "slide-5.jpg", :class => "img-responsive img-full" %>
                </div>
        <!-- Controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="icon-prev"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next">
            <span class="icon-next"></span>
        </a>
</div>
            <h2 class="brand-before">
                <small>Welcome to</small>
            </h2>
            <h1 class="brand-name">Balern Education</h1>
            <hr class="tagline-divider">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

    <div class="box">
        <hr>

        <hr>
            <%= image_tag "intro1.jpg", :class => "img-responsive img-border img-left" %>
            <hr class="visible-xs">

    </div>

    <div class="box">
        <hr>
        <h2 class="intro-text text-center">Balern really
            <strong>Cares</strong>
        </h2>
        <hr>

    </div>    <!-- /.container -->

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="assets/jquery.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="assets/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Script to Activate the Carousel -->
<script>
$('.carousel').carousel({
    interval: 5000 //changes the speed
})
</script>
```

Comment: are you sure all script files are loaded properly ?

Comment: I mean... I guess I am not totally sure, thats kind of what my question is. My implementation method is quite similar to [how this blog setup mailboxer](http://www.sitepoint.com/messaging-rails-mailboxer/). Comparing my application.js file and gemfile to theirs is basically the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling turbolinks. If it starts working properly you either want to remove turbolinks from your project, or install the `jquery-turbolinks` gem

Comment: I already have the `jquery-turbolinks` gem. I edited and added my gemfile above. I tried to remove it and I stell git the same error messages in my chrome inspector and it broke the functionality of my messages code.

Comment: try loading it after turbolinks in the app.js file. Moreover I do not see you requiring the jquery-turbolinks in your app.js

Comment: I think your right about there being something loading improperly, but I still can't seem to fix it. Taking out the `jquery-turbolinks` gem isn't an option as it brings up an error. Everything seems to be functioning the same as when I initially posted. I'll update my code above to show you how it currently looks.

Comment: you need to load chosen after jquery.turbolinks

Comment: This is crazy. I've played with that application.js file for quite a bit now. It seems like no matter what order I use I can't use that chosen form without a page refresh.

Comment: There is some kind of conflict between my twitter-bootstrap dropdown and my  chosen select form. When I reload the page, its often the case that one works and the other doesn't.

Comment: Anything in the console log?

Comment: Ive gone through the code over and over. One thing that I noticed is if I remove the header and the footer I can get the form to fire correctly every time. Both my header and footer have links on them.

Comment: @JoséToy did anyone seem to resolve this in the end I am having the exact same issue

Comment: I honestly forget... I think it had to do with my Application.js file. Make sure you aren't sloppily loading any js scripts in the view itself. Also there are some issues with the order of requirements in the application.js file. The one thing I've learned from this bit is that the assets pipeline is a pain in the ass. Here is the order of my application.js file if that helps.

//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs 
//= require bootstrap
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require chosen-jquery
//= require jquery.image-select
//= require messages
//= require calendar
//= require photos

Comment: @JoséToy turns out my issue was that inside my `layout/application.html.erb` I had `<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>` at the bottom of my layout file. As soon as i moved it to the top everything seem to work okay.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem was with the way I put a piece of code in. I am still not quite sure how to properly do this so if anyone could tell me that would be helpful...

```
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Script to Activate the Carousel -->
<script>
$('.carousel').carousel({
    interval: 5000 //changes the speed
})
</script>
```

I had this in one of my view pages. I assume the problem is that this shouldn't be in a view?

This is what was causing my chosen form and dropdown to misfire